# How can I tell if Eclipse picks up my Maven settings.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven

How do I know if Eclipse picks up my `settings.xml` in `%homepath%/.m2/settings.xml`?

Comment: Simple: write `"I like unicorns"` in it and see if it continues to work.

Comment: Thats a good idea.. Changed the settings.xml to an invalid xml and got error...:) So it is working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to those kind of questions (*"How do I know that my file is being taken into account?"*) are generally answered with a very simple way: make the file invalid and see if it continues to work.

- It it does, your file is ignored.
- It it doesn't, your file isn't ignored.

In this case, just write random words or whatever comes through your mind inside the `settings.xml` file and see if Eclipse throws an error.

---

As a side-note, you can probably be sure that Eclipse will pick it up. Or it is a matter of going into "Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings" and click on "Update Settings".